# Unable to Parametrize Using TestNG in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am new to selenium and trying to parameterize username and password field using testing. This script only opens the URL for me and does nothing more. Can someone help me out here and let me know the appropriate way of achieving this?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

 public class Testcase1 {

  WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver ();
  driver.get("URL");
 // driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

@Test
@Parameters({"sUsername","sPassword"})
public  void login()

{    

    WebElement objUsername = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Username']"));
    objUsername.sendKeys("sUsername");

    WebElement objPassword = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@placeholder,'Password')]"));
    objPassword.sendKeys("sPassword");

    WebElement objLogin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Login')]"));
    objLogin.click();

    if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='LOGOUT']")).isDisplayed())
            {
        System.out.print("Test Case is Passed");
            }
    else
        System.out.print("Test Case is Failed");    
            }

}
```

XML:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Smoke">
  <test name="Testcase1">
    <parameter name="sUsername" value="testuser"></parameter>
  <parameter name="sPassword" value="123"></parameter>
  <classes>
        <class name="org.param.testcases.Testcase1">
        </class>
    </classes>

    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need make following changes :

first :change    `public void login()` to `public void login(String userName, String password)`

and then :

`objUsername.sendKeys("sUsername");`  to   `objUsername.sendKeys(userName);`

`objPassword.sendKeys("sPassword");`  to   `objPassword.sendKeys(password);`

Comment: Thanks for the help, now the script takes username and password from the xml. However, it doesn't navigate to the next screen and fails with exception.

Comment: Now it works, I was passing string instead of variable in my script

Answer (score 0):

remove the import statement from xml and try again.